# Use range with data only- Excel to Access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Basically I have some vba code that exports data from my sheet to a table in my access database, however it also copies all blank rows, is there a way I can get it to ignore the blank rows?
My code as follow:

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\\gaskellc$\SHHDatabase - Copy.mdb"
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:="Tbl_Primary", _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="SHLAA$A1:BM100"

Set acc = Nothing
```

**Edit with Dragons suggestions:**

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim RR As Range
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set RR = Range("A1:BM" & LR)
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\\gaskellc$\SHHDatabase - Copy.mdb "
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
TransferType:=acImport, _
SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
TableName:="Tbl_Primary", _
Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
HasFieldNames:=True, _
Range:=RR

Set acc = Nothing
```

Comment: you neet to `Set RR =` ...

Comment: Hi @DragonSamu, tried that and still get error: "an expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments"

Comment: ah yea, your `Range("A1:BM100" & LR)` should be `Range("A1:BM" & LR)` and don't forget to `Dim RR as Range`

Comment: As you are driving this from excel, could you consider using vba code to create a temp sheet and basically copy only the data you want from your full sheet across to the temp one and then export your temp sheet?

Comment: I have assumed from your statement you may have blank rows in the middle hence my suggestion, if you don't then DragonSamu last comment should work

Comment: Hi @DragonSamu, I've tried your suggestions and still get the same error? Posted the code with changes in original questions. Also Mark this is a temp, its just sometimes there may be more or less so I don't want a set range

Comment: Are the blank rows inside the range?

Comment: Then you will have to do as @MarkMoore said and copy the data over and skipblanks.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is pretty notorious for dirty data. I've had sheets import with hundreds of thousands of blank rows for no practical reason.

You already have a/the ref to the Access Database. Why not just execute some SQL to remove the blank rows?

> !Just be sure to pick a column that you are sure MUST exist for the row
>   to be valid data!

This is per Dragon's very good suggestions code:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim RR As Range
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set RR = Range("A1:BM" & LR)
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\\gaskellc$\SHHDatabase - Copy.mdb "
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
TransferType:=acImport, _
SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
TableName:="Tbl_Primary", _
Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
HasFieldNames:=True, _
Range:=RR

'begin modification
acc.docmd.setwarnings false
acc.docmd.runsql "DELETE * FROM Tbl_Primary WHERE [the name of a column that is guaranteed to contain real data] Is Null"
acc.docmd.setwarnings true
'end modification

Set acc = Nothing
```